# What enable_if or other hint is need for the following overloaded << to compile?

Tags: c++

What is needed to allow the << overload to work?  t.cxx is:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

struct St : std::ostringstream {
    template<typename Tp> St& operator<<( const Tp& value ) { return *this; }
    operator std::string() const { return str(); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& s, const St& ss ) { return 
    s << ss.str(); }
};
struct Memory_type {
    std::string to_string() const { return St() << "s=" << s; }
    const char* s;
};
```

> g++ t.cxx

```
t.cxx: In member function 'std::__cxx11::string Memory_type::to_string() const':
t.cxx:10:46: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'St' and 'const char [3]')
  std::string to_string() const { return St() << "s=" << s; }
                                         ~~~~~^~~~~~~
t.cxx:5:28: note: candidate: St& St::operator<<(const Tp&) [with Tp = char [3]]
  template<typename Tp> St& operator<<( const Tp& value ) { return *this; }
                        ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you inheriting from `std::ostringstream`? Are you trying to create class that can only convert to string your struct? If so, there is no need for inheritance.

Comment: Disregarding the propriety of inheriting from `std::ostringstream`, the code appears to be syntactically valid. https://ideone.com/1AGWMh

Comment: I was trying to compile a certain open source project, following the instructions, in Ubuntu with latest g++, and the build fails because of this error.  I can't open an issue on their site or contact developers.  Similar questions have been asked and they say to use some type of enable_if pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that since C++11 there is an `operator<<` overload that works with rvalue ostreams, see [[ostream.rvalue]](http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.rvalue). This causes the ambiguity, because `St() << "s="` could call the `St::operator<<` overload, or the [ostream.rvalue] one. That can be solved by making the `St::operator<<` overload only valid for lvalues, by adding a `&` ref-qualifier to it:

```
template<typename Tp> St& operator<<( const Tp& value ) &
```

However, that just reveals a further problem, which is that the expression `return St() << "s=" << s;` assumes that the `<<` operators will return the original type, not the `std::ostream&` base class (so that it can implicitly  convert from `St` to `std::string`, which seems like a questionable design). Returning the derived type is not how ostream operations typically work. Operations on `ostream` objects usually return a reference to the base class, not the derived type that was passed to it.

The problem can be solved by using an lvalue object instead of trying to write it all as a single expression on an rvalue:

```
St st;
st << "s=" << s;
return st;
```

This works, because `return st;` sees the original type, not just the `ostream` base class.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in GCC. In contrast, the code works flawlessly on clang and Visual Studio.

edit: apparently, according to the standard (see comments), GCC is correct.

The conflict you have is due to the way GCC deals with rvalue references in this case. GCC has the following definition:

```
template<typename _Ostream, typename _Tp>
inline
typename enable_if<__and_<__not_<is_lvalue_reference<_Ostream>>,
                   __is_convertible_to_basic_ostream<_Ostream>,
                   __is_insertable<
                   __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>,
                   const _Tp&>>::value,
                   __rvalue_ostream_type<_Ostream>>::type
                   operator<<(_Ostream&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
{ .... }
```

This definition will cause ambiguity for any rvalue reference that is convertible to `std::ostream`. As a work-around, you can stop using rvalue references for `std::ostream` and instead write:

```
struct Memory_type {
    std::string to_string() const 
    { 
        // Defining a variable avoids passing an rvalue references of St
        St st;
        return st << "s=" << s; 
    }
    const char* s;
};
```

This should work on all modern compilers.

Comment: _This definition will cause ambiguity for any rvalue reference that is convertible to `std::ostream`._ I'd expect that for any compiler with a correct implementation of [LWG 2534](https://wg21.link/lwg2534) (the precise requirement is unimplementable as currently specified, so GCC gets as close to the intent as we can).

Comment: Thank you pointing this out. It is interesting that << for ostream&&, which is specified in http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.rvalue , is neither in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt(cppreference) , or in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/operator%3C%3C/(cplusplus).

Comment: It's not at either of those pages because they list the `basic_ostream::operator<<` **member functions**, and it's a non-member. It's at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 with the other non-members, see (3), and at cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/operator-free (on the C++11 tab).